# Executing an R-script via C#

Tags: c#, r, cmd

To execute an R-script automaticaly I must type the following in cmd.exe: *"C:\Program Files\R\R-4.1.2\bin\Rscript.exe" "T:\R\Erste_Versuche.R"* (Must be written exactly like this)

The following code already worked with .txt- and .exe -files:

```
string command = @"C:\...\test.txt";
Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/c" + command );
```

Running the following unfortunately does not execute what happens when I type the same manually into cmd.exe

```
string command = @"C:\Program Files\R\R-4.1.2\bin\Rscript.exe";
Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/c" + command );
```

Q1: Why does *"C:\Program Files\R\R-4.1.2\bin\Rscript.exe"* not get executed?

Q2: How to to insert *"C:\Program Files\R\R-4.1.2\bin\Rscript.exe" "T:\R\Erste_Versuche.R"* correctly into cmd.exe ?

Comment: Why is the C# [Process class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process) used being a C# wrapper class for the Windows kernel library function [CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) used with the [STARTUPINFO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/ns-processthreadsapi-startupinfow) to run `cmd.exe` just for running `C:\Program Files\R\R-4.1.2\bin\Rscript.exe` with the argument `T:\R\Erste_Versuche.R` by using the function `CreateProcess`?

Comment: The solution is running directly `C:\Program Files\R\R-4.1.2\bin\Rscript.exe` with the argument `T:\R\Erste_Versuche.R` using the C# `Process` class. It does not matter for the kernel library function `CreateProcess` which executable calls it to create a new process according to the passed arguments and the data in the structure filled by the C# [ProcessStartInfo class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo). The roundabout route via the Windows Command Processor `cmd.exe` is not needed at all here according to posted requirements.

Comment: But if you are really interested in the reason why the used code with `cmd.exe` does not work, open a command prompt window and run `cmd /?` to get displayed the usage help of the Windows Command Processor. There is explained how the argument string(s) after option `/C` are interpreted by `cmd.exe` depending on various criteria and that file names (or other argument strings) containing a space or one of these characters ``&()[]{}^=;!'+,`~`` (or `<>|` not possible in a file name) must be enclosed in `"`. The argument string `C:\Program Files\R\R-4.1.2\bin\Rscript.exe` contains a space.

Comment: So it would be necessary to start `cmd.exe` with the options `/D` (not really needed, but advisable to use in this case), `/S` and `/C` and the command line argument string `""C:\Program Files\R\R-4.1.2\bin\Rscript.exe" "T:\R\Erste_Versuche.R""` appropriately encoded in C# code. It can be seen that using `Process.Start("C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-4.1.2\\bin\\Rscript.exe", "T:\\R\\Erste_Versuche.R");` is easier than `Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/D /S /C \"\"C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-4.1.2\\bin\\Rscript.exe\" \"T:\\R\\Erste_Versuche.R\"\"");` (not tested by myself).

Comment: One more question: Why is `Rscript.exe` executed from with a C# coded application to process an R script because of everything done by the R script can be done also with C# code? Such combined usage of executables just makes a task more complex to handle now and in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working code:

```
string command = @"T:\R\Erste_Versuche.R";
Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files\R\R-4.1.2\bin\Rscript.exe", command);
```

Thank you so much [Mofi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3074564/mofi)! For leading me to an easier solution but also explaining how my complicated approach could have worked.

I decided to use R because it was so much easier for me to visualise the data I have.